# What is the noise level inside the Tu-114's passenger cabin?

Tags: airliner, tu-114

Was the Tu-114 as noisy inside the passenger cabin as the Tu-95 bomber was said to be?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not "as noisy as" due to at least *some* insulation that must have been installed, but by all accounts (including those of my acquaintances who flew it), Tu-114 was by far the noisiest airliner.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-114#Design) quotes the noise level in the cabin of around 110 dB. This is the level when one needs to yell to other's ear to be heard - which is about how it was.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the planes are very similar in design, I would think that the noise might be less if they have sound insulation. They are almost identical planes, and they both have counterrotating propellers. I never knew that the Tu-114 made a distinct noise compared to the bear.

Hope this helps!
Charlie :)

Comment: The Tu-114 was low-wing, and the Tu-95 high-wing. That difference may be significant with regard to the noise perceived inside the plane.